# How can I access to text property for TextEdit that located in mdi subWindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Firstly, look at the following image

[image]

In short, how to get the `content(text)` of `TextEdit`.
Notice: I have created the `MDI subWindow(QWidget)` and `TextEdit` dynamically by code not by Qt design.

The following is the code that wrote to create  the `MDI subWindow` and `TextEdit`:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
QTextEdit *TextEdit = new QTextEdit(widget);
QMdiSubWindow *mdiWindows = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(widget);
mdiWindows->setGeometry(5, 5, 300, 250);
mdiWindows->setWindowTitle(finfo.baseName());
mdiWindows->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
mdiWindows->layout()->addWidget(TextEdit);
mdiWindows->show();
```

**And Now, how can I access to text property for TextEdit to get the content ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the active subwindow is available by `QMdiSubWindow * QMdiArea::activeSubWindow () const`. You can also use the `findChild`  to get a child with a specific name :

```
QTextEdit * textEdit = ui->mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->widget()->findChild<QTextEdit*>("myTextEdit");
```

But you should also set a name for your child widget when creating it :

```
QTextEdit *textEdit = new QTextEdit(widget);
textEdit->setObjectName("myTextEdit");
```

Also `QList<T> QObject::findChildren ( const QString & name = QString() ) const` returns all children with the given name that can be cast to type T. Omitting the name causes all object names to be matched. So you can access all children of the widget by :

```
QList<QTextEdit *> list = ui->mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->widget()->findChildren<QTextEdit *>();
foreach(QTextEdit *w, list)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want to access to the `TextEdit` which its parent `subwindow` is the active window.

Comment: @LionKing Getting the active subwindow is available by `QMdiSubWindow * QMdiArea::activeSubWindow () const`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mr `@Nejat`, Please can you tell me what is purpose of the `widget()` function ?

Comment: It returns the current internal widget inside the returned `QMdiSubWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

[QTextEdit::plainText()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop) should get you there. Obviously, you'll need to keep a pointer to the `QTextEdit` that you've dynamically created around.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same question wrt PyQt/PySide (like me): to access the current widget in the active subwindow, use the following:

`txtWidget=myQMdiArea.activeSubWindow().widget()`